# Why did Iron Man not upload his complete memory onto a computer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, why could Iron Man not do something like in the movie *Transcendance*, i.e to upload his complete memory onto a computer? He made Vision, so he could have done this.

In *Infinity War* Hulk speaks with Black Panther's sister about connecting neurons to Vision's stone, so they know about this knowledge. Why did Iron man not work on this even though he feared his death so much?

Even in civil war, Iron man talked in MIT recording his tramatic memory which he displays in hologram of his younger age.So he has access to his momery.

Comment: If you have anything that suggests that this was ever remotely an option considered in the story, feel free to add that. But as it stands, this is really just you making up your own story, based on what some totally unrelated random other film showed, and asking why *that* wasn't how the film went. If there's a limit to "why didn't the writers think like I did?" questions, it's the point where there's zero connection between your *proposed* storyline and the actual film.

Comment: Shuri's operation on Vision was to allow him to survive without the Mind Stone. It could only have been done on Vision, due to his android body, and had absolutely nothing to do uploading someone's memory onto a computer.

Comment: "[Tony] made Vision" only be extension that he made Ultron who then made Vision which one might as well said your grandfather made you

Comment: hoho....i posted this question before..spiderman ffh ...proud of my self...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Because he can't**

There is no indication that Tony has this kind of technology.

J.A.R.V.I.S./Vision was an Artificial Intelligence system, not the memory of an actual person.

Comment: But what about B. A. R. F. I thought it was similar to uploading memories

Comment: Only Cave Johnson has this technology. And lemons.

Comment: Arnim Zola had this technology

Comment: Zola and his mainframe were kept secret from non Hydra affiliated personnel for a long time, and destroyed soon after they were revealed, so Tony may have known Zola did it but never had an opportunity to learn precisely how it was done.

Comment: Also, the entity on that mainframe *claimed* to be Zola, but I think it's worth pointing out that even the flesh and blood Zola was not the most reliable narrator.