# Where is Iron Man's memory stored?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, Tony Stark explains an experiment at MIT in which he projects his memory of his conversation with his parents in a hologram. He ha also invested around 600 million in this project, as said by him.

So did Tony have to extract his complete memory and store it somewhere?

Then why can't Iron Man's complete memory be extracted to create a synthetic Iron Man after his death?

Comment: It will only be his "Memories" after all, you can't create another intelligence just by gathering the memories.

Comment: [Related, but not a duplicate](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100343/46980).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So Iron had to extract his complete memory and stored it some where ?

## His memory is stored in his brain

The glasses he's wearing are used to access the memory and the rest of the system merely projects it.

[image]

He mentions:

> Binarily Augmented Retro-Framing, or BARF. God, I gotta work on that acronym. An extremely costly method of **hijacking the [hippocampus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocampus#Role_in_memory)** to… clear traumatic memories.